# $('#form').submit() works but document.getElementById('form').submit() does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

On ASP.NET Web Forms page where there is any form, I am unable to submit using plain javascript, but using jQuery I am able to submit.

Example:

```
[...]
<head>
    [...]
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitting() { 
        alert('Submitting');
        return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <form id="testform" onsubmit="return submitting();"></form>
     [...]
</body>
[...]
```

Then in the console:

```
> $('#testform')
[<form id=​"testform" onsubmit=​"return submitting()​;​">​</form>​]
```

Then as expected calling .submit() works as expected

```
> $('#testform').submit()
```

Works!

But using document.getElementById:

```
> document.getElementById("testform")
<form id=​"testform" onsubmit=​"return submitting()​;​">​</form>​
> document.getElementById("testform").submit()
undefined
```

I believe that `document.getElementById("testform").submit()` is actually causing a postback, but I am not sure why it will not submit the form as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: `myform.onsubmit()` does work as expected, but why would `myform.submit()` not trigger onsubmit, while `$('#myform').submit() would?

Comment: Because jQuery does it manually for you in a manner similar to that which I did above. Don't forget that jQuery event handlers are an abstraction from the native event handling system.

Comment: Weirdness in the commenting system. First it double posted my comment, then when I deleted one, the other went away too. Anyway, `myform.onsubmit(); myform.submit();` was what I posted above, just so things make sense.

Comment: Why would submit() work for forms that are not part of an asp-classic web app. For instance, I can submit using myform.submit() on google.com, without trouble.

Comment: I'd imagine in those cases there's no handler to invoke. As you mentioned, using `.submit()` does cause a postback. It just doesn't invoke the handler.

Comment: Working fine for me in a quick test. Most likely you have some typo in your real code e.g. `document.getElementById("#testform").submit()` or you indeed have element named "submit" in there.

Comment: I believe this problem is specific to ASP web forms, was this the case for you?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: When you say it works fine, are you saying that the `onsubmit` handler is invoked as well as the `form` being submitted?

Comment: @cookiemonster yes, typing in the console `document.getElementById("testform").submit()` and hitting Enter did submit the form. Handler won't be called "by design" though.

Comment: I think that's what BenM was asking about. The question mentioned that the postback is working, but not the handler. *(I guess the comments mentioned that. The last sentence of the question is a little unclear.)*

Comment: Yes, I was wondering as to why `onsubmit()` was not called as expected when done using `document.getElementById("testform").submit()` as opposed to `$("#testform").submit().

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and figured out the reason/solution:

the `<input type="submit"..>` has *`id="submit"`* which is unnecessary. If you have this ID then remove it and it will submit the form using

document.getElementById("testform").submit()

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I spent nearly 3 freaking hours fighting as to why my form wasn't submitting properly. In my case it was by having `name = submit` on the `<input type="submit">` element, which *also* prevented jQuery `submit()` from working. Those [DOM conflict](http://kangax.github.io/domlint/) are document in [various jQuery Bugs](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1414)

Comment: Thank you, was looking for this as well. I also had the name attribute set to submit!

Comment: Almost 5 years later and you helped me keep what little hair I still have - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I believe .submit() is a jQuery method/function, which is why it only worked in your jQuery example.

The vanillaJS method would be .onSubmit (like the others have mentioned).

Now if you put your code inside of a jQuery wrapper like this:

```
$(document.getElementById("testform"))
```

(Which is basically what jQuery does)

Then you would be able to use .submit() like

```
$(document.getElementById("testform")).submit()
```

I very rarely use .submit(), so I'm not 100% on that, but it looks right to me

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's also a native `.submit()`

Comment: Hmm! I wasn't aware of that. Thanks! (I haven't done much work with forms yet)